# Wait for Parse Query to finish [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to use a Parse Query to fill up an ArrayList. I understand that findInBackground() is async, so it does not necessarily finish running before the rest of the code is executed on the main thread. However, my next function in the main thread requires that the ArrayList is filled. How can I wait for the findInBackground() callback to finish before I proceed with the next function?

This is my first time working with android studio and java, so any advice or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

after you get response, callback's method done is called and you can add your code inside this method and handle the result.

Example:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery("SOME_CLASS");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            //here you can add your code 
            //you get your result as a List of parse objects - objects
        }
    });
```